# how to fix cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) Invalid number of channels in input image:, this error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i am getting this error

```
  File "E:\demo3\modules\modelTrain.py", line 179, in grayscaleImage
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

I am getting error at this line

```
gry = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

my complete code

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import sys, os
from myconstants1 import path_logs, path_resources
from logConfig1 import setup_logger
import pathlib, pycountry, cv2, pickle, random, PIL, sys
from pathlib import Path 
import pathlib as pl
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from glob import glob
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

logger = setup_logger('/modelTrain', path_logs+'/modelTrain.log')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

path = sys.path
path = Path(__file__).parent

print("path2", path)

class HandleRequest5(Resource):
    y_validation = ""
    x_test = ""
    x_validation  = ""
    x_train = ""
         
    @classmethod
    def post(cls, json): 
               
        data = request.get_json()
        
        json = ({
            "Status": "failed",
            "message": "ALL fields are mandatory"
                })
                
        try:
            country_code = data["country_code"].upper()  
            batch_size = data["batch_size"]
            step_per_epoch_val = data["step_per_epoch_val"]
            epoch = data["epoch"]
        except KeyError:
            print(json)
            logger.debug(json)
            return(json)

        
        try:
            country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3 = data["country_code"].upper()).name.lower()
            print("country1", country)
            logger.debug(f'country1 : {country}')
            country = country.split()
            country =("_".join(country))
            print("country : ", country)
            logger.debug(f"country : {country}")
            alpha_2 = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3 = data["country_code"].upper()).alpha_2
            print("alpha_2 : ", alpha_2)
            logger.debug(f"alpha_2 : {alpha_2}")
        except AttributeError:                
            jsonify1 = {
                        "status": "invalid",
                        "message" : "Invalid country_code"
                        }
            print("invalid country_code")
            
            logger.debug({
                        "status": "invalid",
                        "message" : "Invalid country_code"
                        })
            return jsonify1
    
    #   path = rf'{path}/{country}'  # folder with all class folders
        
        labelFile = rf'{path_resources}/{country}/labels.csv'         
        imageDimensions = (99, 200, 3)
        print("imageDimensions:", imageDimensions)
        testRatio = 0.2               # if 1000 images split will 200 for testing
        validationRatio = 0.2  
        print("line 91 is going to execute")
        cls.importImages( cls,testRatio , validationRatio , imageDimensions  ,country , labelFile)   
        
    def importImages(cls, testRatio, validationRatio, imageDimensions, country, labelFile):
        count = 0
        images = []
        classNo = []
        

        p = pl.Path(f'{path_resources}/{country}')                    
        mylist = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
        print("mylist1", mylist)
        print("total classs detected :", len(mylist))
        noofClasses = len(mylist)
        print("noofClasses:", noofClasses)
        print("importing classes...")
        
        for x in range(0, len(mylist)):

            myPicList = os.listdir(os.path.join(str(path_resources), str(country)+'//'+str(count))) 
            print("myPicList1:", myPicList)

            #for y in myPicList:
                #print(os.path.join(path, str(count), y))
                #curImg = cv2.imread((str(path_resources)+"/"+str(count)+"//"+y))
                
            for y in myPicList:
                print(os.path.join(path_resources, country, str(count)+y))

                curImg = cv2.imread(f"{path_resources}{country}/{str(count)}//{y}")                                                      
                images.append(curImg)
                classNo.append(count)
            print(count, end = " ")
            count+=1
        print(" ")
        images = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8) 
        images = np.array(images)
        print("line 128")
        print(images.shape)        
        #images = np.append(images,4)
        #images = images.append((Image.fromarray(images, dtype=np.float32).convert('RGB') / 255.))
#        image = Image.fromarray(images)
        #images = images.convert("RGB")
        classNo = np.array(classNo)        
        
        cls.splitData(cls, images, classNo, testRatio, validationRatio , imageDimensions, labelFile, noofClasses)
        return images, classNo, noofClasses
        
        # split data #
    def splitData(cls, images, classNo, testRatio, validationRatio , imageDimensions, labelFile, noofClasses):

        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, classNo, test_size = testRatio)
        x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(x_train, y_train , test_size = validationRatio)
        
        # to check if no of images matches to number of labels for each data set
        print("data shapes...")
        print("train : ", end = "");print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
        print("validation :", end = ""); print(x_validation.shape, y_validation.shape) 
        print("test :", end = ""); print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)        
        
        assert (x_train.shape[0] == y_train.shape[0]),  "the no of images is not equal to the no of labels in training set"
        assert (x_validation.shape[0] == y_validation.shape[0]), "the no of images is not equal to the no of labels in validation set"
        assert (x_test.shape[0] == y_test.shape[0]), "the no of images is not equal to the no of labels in test set"
        #print(x_train.shape)
        assert (x_train.shape[1:]  == (imageDimensions)),  "the dimension of training images are wrong"
        assert (x_validation.shape[1:] == (imageDimensions)), "the dimension of validation images are wrong"
        assert (x_test.shape[1:] == (imageDimensions)), "the dimension of test images are wrong"        
        
        data = pd.read_csv(labelFile) 
        
        cls.grayscaleImage( images, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test )
        
        return images, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test
    
    # preprocessing the image #

    @classmethod    
    def grayscaleImage(cls,images, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test):
        ret_lst = []
        for image in images:
            print("line 172")
            print(image.ndim == 2)                 
            print("line 175")
            print(image.shape)
            print("line 177")
            image= np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
            print(image.dtype)
            gry = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret_lst.append(gry)
        image = np.array(ret_lst, dtype=np.uint8)
        print("line 178")
        print(image.shape)
        cls.equalize( cls,image, ret_lst,  x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation)
        return image, ret_lst, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation  

    def equalize(cls,image, ret_lst, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation):
            image = np.array(image)
            image = image.astype(np.uint8) 
            print(image.dtype)
            hist,bins = np.histogram(image.flatten(),256,[0,256])
            cdf = hist.cumsum()
            cdf_normalized = cdf * float(hist.max()) / cdf.max()
            plt.plot(cdf_normalized, color = 'b')
            plt.hist(image.flatten(),256,[0,256], color = 'r')
            plt.xlim([0,256])
            plt.legend(('cdf','histogram'), loc = 'upper left')
            #plt.show()
            cls.preprocessing( image, ret_lst,  x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation)
            return image , ret_lst, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation
    
    @classmethod
    def preprocessing(cls, image, equalize, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation):
        images1 = cls.grayscaleImage(image, x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test)
        images1 = equalize(images1)   #standardize the lightining of an image
        images1 = images1/255         # to normaize value between 0 and 1 instead of 0 to 255
        return images1 , x_train, x_validation, x_test, y_train, y_test, y_validation       
        
        x_train = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, x_train)))  # to iterate and preprocess all images
        x_validation = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, x_validation)))
        x_test = np.array(list(map(preprocessing, x_test)))

        #cv2.imshow("grayscale images", x_train[random.randint(0, len(x_train)-1)]) #to check if training is done properly
               
        # add a depth of 1 #

        x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)
        x_validation = x_validation.reshape(x_validation .shape[0], x_validation .shape[1], x_validation .shape[2], 1)
        x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], x_test.shape[2], 1)


    def dataAugmentation(cls, x_train, y_train, noofClasses):
    # augmentation of images to make it more generic #

        dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range = 0.1, 
                             height_shift_range  = 0.1,
                             zoom_range = 0.2,
                             shear_range = 0.1,
                             rotation_range = 10)

        dataGen.fit(x_train)
        batches = dataGen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 20)
        x_batch, y_batch = next(batches)


# to show augmentated image sample 
#fig, axs = plt.subplots(24, 2, figsize = (20, 5))
#fig.tight_layout()
#print(axs)
#print("axs0:",axs[0])
#print("axs1:",axs[1])
#for i in range(10):
    #axs[i].imshow(x_batch[i].reshape(imageDimensions[0], imageDimensions[1]))
    #axs[0][1].imshow(x_batch[i].reshape(imageDimensions[0], imageDimensions[1]))
    #axs[i].axis("off")
    #axs[0][1].axis('off')
#plt.show()

        y_train = to_categorical(y_train, noofClasses) 
        y_validation = to_categorical(y_validation, noofClasses) 
        y_test = to_categorical(y_test, noofClasses) 
        cls.splitData(y_validations)        
        cls.myModel(noofClasses)
# convolution neural network #

    def myModel(cls, noofClasses, country):
        no_of_filters = 60 
        size_of_filter = (5,5)  #this is kernal that move around the image to get the features 
    
        size_of_filter2 = (3,3) 
        size_of_pool = (2,2)
        no_of_nodes = 200
    
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(no_of_filters, size_of_filter, input_shape = (imageDimensions[0], imageDimensions[1], 1), activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(no_of_filters, size_of_filter, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = size_of_pool))
    
        model.add(Conv2D(no_of_filters//2, size_of_filter2, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(no_of_filters//2, size_of_filter2, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(no_of_nodes, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    
  #  model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(noofClasses, activation = "softmax"))
    
    # compile model #
        model.compile(Adam(lr = 0.001), loss = "categorical_crossentropy",  metrics = ["accuracy"])
        return model    
    
    # train #
        model = myModel()

        print(model.summary())
        history = model.fit_generator  (dataGen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size_val), steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch_val, epochs = epoch_val, validation_data = (x_train, y_train))  
        
# plot #

        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
        plt.plot(history.history["val_loss"])
        plt.legend(["training", "validation"])

        plt.title("loss")
        plt.xlabel("epoch")
        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot(history.history["accuracy"])
        plt.plot(history.history["val_accuracy"])

        plt.legend(["training", "accuracy"])
        plt.title("accuracy")
        plt.xlabel("epoch")
        #plt.show()


        score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 0)
        print("test score: ", score[0])
        print("test accuracy: ", score[1])

    ###############################################################
    #store the model as pickle object #
    #save_path = rf'{path}/{country}'
        pickle_out = open(rf"{path_resources}/{country}.p", "wb")
    #model = model.save(rf'{country}_{epoch_val}.h5')

        pickle.dump(model, pickle_out)
        pickle_out.close()
        print(rf"{country}_model saved...")
        cv2.waitKey(0)        

        
api.add_resource(HandleRequest5, '/modelTrain')
if __name__ == ' __main__ ':
    app.run(debug = False)
```